# Our civilization on Earth collapses; subsequent civilization discovers our technology

Tags: story-identification, ancient-races

I'm looking for a science fiction book that is about the discovery of an ancient technological civilization on Earth in the far future .  The discoverer's civilization is not highly technological, and they awaken an artificial intelligence.

I don't know much more about the book - hopefully my description is not too vague.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: When did you read this? And where? In English? Was it a book or a story within a set of stories? We have a checklist at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info. Even if you think you don't remember more details, please go down the list and see if anything sparks a memory (even a "I think it might have had this..." detail is useful) and edit it into your question.

Comment: It's pretty vague. The future civilization isn't "highly" technological. So what kind of technology do they have? Wheels? Sails? Metals? Steam engines? Photography? Electricity?

Comment: Why did our civilization collapse? Was it caused by a plague? A meteor impact? Climate change? Atomic war?

Comment: I can think of at least a dozen short stories and several novels that fit this trope - can you provide any more details?

Comment: It might be Eternity Road, by Jack McDevitt.  The part with the ai has stayed with me.

Comment: Thanks dosco jones, i believe that's the book - just in time too. Lol

Comment: Asked and answered.